# Calculating marginal probability

Tags: probability

I am trying to solve an example for Bayes theorem practice. Here is the situation:

*In a shop, people can take chewing gum from a dispenser on the right, or the left. The dispenser on the right has 7 packets of mint gum, and 3 packets of fruit gum, and the dispenser on the left has 7 packets of mint gum and 7 packets of fruit gum.*

I am just trying to find the probability of picking a mint; P(M). I used the idea of contingency tables.

I am getting the answer as 14/24, which is being marked as incorrect. Can I please get help where I might be going wrong? Help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: There are a lot of probabilities missing from this question, but assuming all choices are uniform I get 3/5 (the average of 7/10 and 7/14). Where does 14/24 come from?

Comment: @harold, I agree with your answer. But can you please help me to understand where I am wrong. I am just using the concept of joint probabilities: P(M)=P(M,right dispenser)+P(M, left dispenser). If we draw the contingency table using two categorical variables; dispenser and gum, we get the above sum as 7/24 +7/24. please correct me if I am wrong. thanx for helping me to learn

Comment: Why are you posting this on Stack Overflow? Why not [mathematics.se]?

Comment: The equation P(M)=P(M,right dispenser)+P(M, left dispenser) in itself is correct. But how did you get 7/24 from each one of the summands? See the solution I provided below, this may explain your mistake.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a math question rather than a programming question.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about [math.se] instead of programming or software development.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve it using the Law of total probability:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_probability

In particular,

P(M)=P(M|right dispenser)*P(right dispenser)+P(M|left dispenser)*P(left dispenser)=(7/10)*(1/2)+(7/14)*(1/2)=(6/5)*(1/2)=3/5.

This solution assumes that all choices are uniform.